# Como decriptar código encriptado com JS eval function em massa

Tags: javascript, html, eval

Ola gostaria de saber como posso decriptar em massa códigos encriptados com JS eval function, eu estou com um encriptador e decriptador que realiza o processo perfeitamente com tudo eu estou necessitando que o processo de descript seja realizado em massa, mais o código que eu possuo, só realiza um processo de descript por vez no campo do formulário.

Ou seja se eu tiver mais de um código encriptado como no exemplo abaixo, a função que realiza o processo de descript não funciona.

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('6://e.4.2/d/7-3-5-b-c-1-3-5-a-9-0.8',62,15,'82754461|bola|com|de|dreamstime|futebol|https|jogador|jpg|movimento|no|que|retrocede|t|thumbs'.split('|'),0,{}))

eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}('6://8.3.1/a/4-2-5-2-9-0.7',62,11,'45933265|com|do|dreamstime|fundo|futebol|https|jpg|thumbs|vintage|z'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Eu gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de adaptar o código abaixo para que realize esse tipo de processo em massa.

Formulário de encriptar e decriptar código

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>
            Descriptador e Encriptador
        </title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            a = 62;
            function encode() {
                var code = document.getElementById('code').value;
                code = code.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, '');
                code = code.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
                var tmp = code.match(/\b(\w+)\b/g);
                tmp.sort();
                var dict = [];
                var i, t = '';
                for (var i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
                    if (tmp[i] != t) dict.push(t = tmp[i]);
                }
                var len = dict.length;
                var ch;
                for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    ch = num(i);
                    code = code.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + dict[i] + '\\b', 'g'), ch);
                    if (ch == dict[i]) dict[i] = '';
                }
                document.getElementById('code').value = "eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--)d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c);k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\\\w+'};c=1};while(c--)if(k[c])p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\\\b'+e(c)+'\\\\b','g'),k[c]);return p}(" + "'" + code + "'," + a + "," + len + ",'" + dict.join('|') + "'.split('|'),0,{}))";
            }

            function num(c) {
                return (c < a ? '': num(parseInt(c / a))) + ((c = c % a) > 35 ? String.fromCharCode(c + 29) : c.toString(36));
            }

            function run() {
                eval(document.getElementById('code').value);
            }

            function decode() {
                var code = document.getElementById('code').value;
                code = code.replace(/^eval/, '');
                document.getElementById('code').value = eval(code);
            }
        </script>
        <textarea id='code' cols=80 rows=20>
        </textarea>
        <br>
                 <input type=button onclick=decode() value=decrypt>
                 <input type=button onclick=encode() value=encryption>
    </body>

</html>
```